# Tray Icon Context Menu without hidden Form

Tags: powershell

I've been experimenting with tray icons & context menus in PowerShell for some time. However, i can only get the context menu to work correctly when a Form is called in the same script.

Here is a small example:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Windows.Forms"

$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$objNotifyIcon = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon 
$objContextMenu = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu
$objExitMenuItem = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem

$objExitMenuItem.Index = 1
$objExitMenuItem.Text = "Exit"
$objExitMenuItem.add_Click({ 
$objForm.Close() 
$objNotifyIcon.visible = $false 
})
$objContextMenu.MenuItems.Add($objExitMenuItem) | Out-Null

$objNotifyIcon.Icon = "$PSScriptRoot\win.ico"
$objNotifyIcon.Text = "Context Menu"

$objNotifyIcon.ContextMenu = $objContextMenu
$objForm.ContextMenu = $objContextMenu

#Enabling Icon in Taskbar
$objNotifyIcon.Visible = $true

#Hiding Form as best as possible
$objForm.Visible = $false
$objForm.WindowState = "minimized"
$objForm.ShowInTaskbar = $false
$objForm.add_Closing({ $objForm.ShowInTaskBar = $False }) 

$objForm.ShowDialog()
```

As soon as the Form componets are removed, the Context menu wont work correctly.
Does anyone know why you need this Form to be loaded and is there a way around it?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: PowerShell is for automation (i.e. little or no user interaction).  Just because you can hook into the UI elements of .NET, etc doesn't mean you should use them.  If you want a desktop app, you should write it directly in some other language, say, C#/WPF, as that's what they are designed for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext is what you need to use to acheive that.